# Simple Informational Page with a Survey Link

Tags: survey, survey-list

Sorry for the newbie question but I was assigned to create a one pager in SharePoint where there are like text above and a survey link below. Is it a good idea to use the built-in survey app?

Our company does not have Microsoft Forms.

Preview:

```
Person 1
email1@email.com
Sched: 10AM to 7PM

Person 2
email2@email.com
Sched: 10AM to 7PM

Person 3
email3@email.com
Sched: 11AM to 8PM


**Do you want to leave a feedback? Click the survey link below:**
http://htttps://somelink.sharepoint.com/some-team/some-survey.aspx
```

Thank you.

And how do I go about it? I am already an owner in our SharePoint.

Comment: The default survey app is still in classic experience. So you won't be able to add it on a modern page.

Comment: @a1th42 Thanks for the information. So I need to drop the default survey app option, do you have a suggestion on how I can accomplish my task? Microsoft Forms cannot be used as well.

Comment: Any feedback on this question?

Comment: I am thinking of SharePoint lists and then another link below for a Microsoft Forms survey.

Comment: Can you use Forms ? If yes you can add a Forms webpart on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Just to go off on a tangent, you might like to check out Survey Monkey for this, if you don't mind using something separate to Sharepoint.

You could embed the survey link in a Sharepoint Announcement or page or in an email if you wished.